# Cassandra JDBC driver does not support float to double

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, logstash, datastax-java-driver

I'm using Datastax Cassandra JDBC driver to connect logstash with cassandra. The driver is trying to convert a column `latitude` of type `float` to `double`. The following exception is being thrown:

`Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::ComDatastaxDriverCoreExceptions::CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [float <-> java.lang.Double]>}`

It works well if the column type in cassandra is `double`, but with `float` it throws this error.
But the problem is, I can't change the type of column, since I have a lot of data in the table and moving to a new table won't be feasible for the application.

Is there a way I can modify something in the JDBC driver to make this work?

Comment: Cant we just store it in a float variable by calling getFloat

Comment: Not really. The problem is that the driver is not able to perform the conversion and give me the values to operate on. The exception is thrown from the driver itself.